# Opening command prompt since Windows Explorer: why are environment variables not updated?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, cmd.exe

I often open the command prompt from a folder in Windows Explorer by  typing cmd + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

[image]

I noticed that by doing so, if I have changed something in my environment variables (e.g. `PATH`, through System properties ==> Advanced system settings ==> Environment Variables) after I opened the Windows Explorer window but before I opened the command prompt, then when I open the command prompt, my modifications in environment variables are not present. E.g. if I open a Windows Explorer window, change PATH to change my Python interpreter, then open a command prompt from the Windows Explorer window, my Python interpreter has not changed. It works fine if I open the command prompt through Start -> Run -> cmd though.

Why, and is there anyway to fix this behavior?

Comment: It's because `explorer` received its environment list from the system at the time it was started. Unfortunately, the same `explorer` also manages the desktop, so you cannot simply exit and restart: you need to kill the process completely, which has some side-effects you may not like. The only work-round is to use one of the many `explorer` alternatives, which can easily be restarted; or of course to run from Start -> Run, as you have found,

Comment: well, change the habit, click start then cmd<ENTER>